# Some issues from migrating my application from flutter 1.22.6 to 3.x.x

Tags: flutter, dart, optimization, duplicates, migration

I would be appreciate if you could help me with the issues below.
When a specific button is pressed, the function is being called more than once, causing unwanted behavior.
this problem originated after migrating my application from flutter 1.22.6 to 3.x.x

I assume that the error is when doing a function.call().
botonConfimar is the widget which is called sometimes than once

Purpose of the button:

- The button's purpose is to perform a specific action.

Type of bug:

- The bug is a function duplication issue.

Possible solution:

- The possible solution to the problem is to optimize the code logic.
  Looking forward to hearing from you.
  Thanks a ton.

I tried to optimize the code logic.

Comment: Can you include the code for botonConfimar? That might provide the basis for someone to help you find a solution.